# How to list cluster in Dataproc with Java API

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, service-accounts, dataproc

I need to access dataproc by authenticating with a Service Account json key and get the list of clusters, through a command quite similar to "gcloud dataproc clusters list". I am using the Java API, I have viewed the documentation but have not found a way to do this.
Does anyone have a code snippet with which it is possible to do this?

Comment: Did you try following [this](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-dataproc/v1beta2-rev20191031-1.28.0/com/google/api/services/dataproc/v1beta2/Dataproc.Projects.Regions.Clusters.html#list-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) documentation